# query multiple tables with knex.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I want to render with `Expres.js` and `knex.js` two tables using for that only one get function in order to use the data from both tables in one HTML template. It works when I query only one table (schools or students) but I don't know how to do with two tables.
Any suggestion?

```
app.get('/schools', function(req, res) {

    knex.select()
    .from('schools', 'students')
    .then(function(schools, students) {
        res.render('schools', {
            schools: schools,
            students: students
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your approach indeed works, however i suggest you this idiom in order to avoid the [promise hell](https://dzone.com/articles/common-promise-mistakes) (see the link for even better examples.)

```
router.get("/schools",function(req,res){
  var schools
  knex("schools").select().then(function(ret){
    schools=ret
    return knex("students").select()
  }).then(function(students){
    res.render("schools",{
      students: students,
      schools: schools
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! it works in the same way as the one I posted but the structure is better.

Comment: This is bad as you are revisiting the database several times. Use Join instead.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `join` to use multiple tables on the basis of some `reference key`
Here is `example` of join two tables at with reference key

table 1:**users** And table2: **accounts**

And reference key is `user's primary key`

```
.then(function() {
  return knex('users')
    .join('accounts', 'users.id', 'accounts.user_id')
    .select('users.user_name as user', 'accounts.account_name as account');
})
```

Hope this can give you better idea.

For more reference see the [Docs](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex)

Comment: Thank you for your answer adbulbarik, but using join I will create a one table with the data together, but what I wanted was to render two tables. May be I didn't explain properly. Luckily I found the way that works and I will post it.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, to the problem and it is working, just adding a new query to the .then of the previous one and passing it as an argument so I can render both tables to the same .html and use them independently.

```
    knex.select()
    .from('schools')
    .then(function(schools){
        knex.select()
        .from('students')
        .then(function(students) {
            res.render('schools', {
                students: students,
                schools: schools
            });
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Just a heads up that while this does work, you're effectively performing 2 transactions this way. In that way, this is actually less performant than an internal join statement.