# Select from multiple table with knex.js

Tags: knex.js

How to run this query:

```
select * from table1, table2;
```

with knex.js?

I've tried this:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: { filename: ':memory:' },
})

async function main() {
  await knex.schema.createTable('table1', table => table.string('field1'))
  await knex.schema.createTable('table2', table => table.string('field2'))
  await knex.insert({ field1: 'value' }).into('table1')
  await knex.insert({ field2: 'value' }).into('table2')
  await knex.from('table1', 'table2')   // first attempt
  await knex.from(['table1', 'table2']) // second attempt
}

main().catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

I run that code with env `DEBUG='knex:query'` and got this output:

```
create table `table1` (`field1` varchar(255))
create table `table2` (`field2` varchar(255))
insert into `table1` (`field1`) values (?)
insert into `table2` (`field2`) values (?)
select * from `table1`
select * from `table1` as `0`, `table2` as `1`
```

clearly, the `select` statement is not what I expected.

**PS:**

in case you mark this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631240/query-multiple-tables-with-knex-js), it is not.
the main point of question is different and the answer in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631240/query-multiple-tables-with-knex-js)
doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
knex.from('table1').crossJoin('table2')
```

Generates the sql `select * from table1 cross join table2`

I'm testing with postgres, not sqlite, but these two statements are getting the same output:

```
select * from table1, table2;
select * from table1 cross join table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

One can always use [knex.raw](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-raw) for database-specific and any other complicated custom logic.

Try this one (it produces desired output):

```
knex
    .select('*')
    .from(knex.raw('table1, table2'))
```